# Is this possible to create a partition which be accessible but invisible by TrueCrypt and C#?

Tags: c#, hidden, truecrypt, disk-partitioning

I have a folder in CD/DVD and want to make its contents invisible, accessible and encrypted.
So I decide to use TrueCrypt for making that folder as encrypted hidden volume.But with this method , user can see new volume contents after it mounted. So I want to know Is this possible to make the mounted volume accessible but invisible? and Is there any other solution to do that by programming in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Only need to write a few of code to produce registry file for hide truecrypt drive. For example I make hide truecrypt drive known as `Z:`. First, open notepad and enter this code.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoDrives"=hex:00,00,00,02
```

Then save this file name as `hideZ.reg`. Then you double click this file and restart your pc. After finished restart, drive `Z:` (truecrypt drive is invisible form My Computer). Important is you truecrypt drive letter is `Z:`.